# How to match data using Excel or Access

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master sheet with 10,000 entries that has a common identifier in column A. I have many other sheets that have data and the same common ID, but for smaller populations. For example, there is a sheet for 1,500 senior citizens. Column A is the unique ID, Column B is a y for SENIOR_CITIZEN. How do I match these two sheets so that in my master there will be a new column in the master identifies the matches from the 1500 IDs from the senior citizen sheet to the 10,000 IDs on the master? VLOOKUP won't work because there are way more entries in the master than in the senior citizen file.

Comment: You can probably use a combination of INDEX and MATCH.  Do some research; try some solutions, and post back if you run into problems, showing what you've done and what problems you've run into.

Comment: Also, what are the names of your sheets?  It's tricky coding when you don't know what to type for values.   Is Column A the same format on both sheets?

Comment: I have tried a few variation of INDEX and MATCH to no avail. As well as Microsoft Query, and some SQL queries using Access... Column A is labeled the same on both sheets and all the entries in the senior citizen sheet have a matching entry on the main page. The master sheet is MAIN and the example senior citizen sheet is SENIOR_CITIZEN. I am not a data/IT guy but "inherited" some work when another employee left.

Comment: I know the feeling of that.  You came to the right place, feel free to browse my other answers by clicking on my userName. There might be some other questions in there that you can benefit from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using simple loops, this is very easy to accomplish.**  I'm not sure if I understood your question exactly, but I'm pretty certain this is what you want.

**Note:** in the code, I use Cells(sRow, "B") once and (tRow, 2) another time.  They accomplish the same thing, and I'm writing it like that to show you how it works.  You can either set the column value with a letter or a "LONG" typed variable.  This lets you use a counter and loop through the rows and columns, skipping about however you see fit, logically for your needs.

Not knowing your sheet names, using "Seniors" and "Master":

**TESTED:**

```
Sub SeniorMatch()

Dim sh1 As String
Dim sh2 As String
Dim lastRow1 As Long    'For sh1
Dim lastRow2 As Long    'sh2
Dim tempID As String    'In case you use any letters in your ID

sh1 = "Seniors" 'Set the Sheet Names
sh2 = "Master"

lastRow1 = Sheets(sh1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
lastRow2 = Sheets(sh2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'using sRow for SOURCE Row, and tRow for Target Row

For sRow = 2 To lastRow1
    If Sheets(sh1).Cells(sRow, "B").Value = LCase("y") Then
        tempID = Sheets(sh1).Cells(sRow, 1).Text
        For tRow = 2 To lastRow2
            If Sheets(sh2).Cells(tRow, 1) = tempID Then
                Sheets(sh2).Cells(tRow, 2) = "y"    'Set col B to "y"
            End If
        Next tRow
    End If
Next sRow

End Sub
```

[image: Seniors]
[image: RESULT]

Comment: This is exactly what I want!!! Thank you, I duplicated your results so now I will make it work for my several sheets with several thousand entries. You rock!

Comment: If I wanted collect numbers unique to the ID instead of 'y's from column 2 of sheet 1, how would I alter the code?

Comment: in the code above, the tempID is the ID.  So you could just store that value somewhere else instead of searching for it on the Master sheet.  You could do both...  Keep in mind, this is still on the row at the time it discovers the "y", so you can still get anything off that row very easily at that time.   What would you do with them once you collect them?

Comment: I would want to put them in the master sheet. For example, matching social security numbers stored in a smaller sheet with my master sheet. I assume I would change'Sheets(sh2).Cells(tRow, 2) = "y"' to do this?

Comment: In the code above, say the tRow = 5, then it's checking A5 for a match, and writing a "y" in B5.  If you want to write the tempID(ssn) somewhere, you would just say '[destination] = tempID '.  I just used simple integers for the ID.